# Lighttpd rewrite rule which works with or without a trailing slash

Tags: lighttpd

I'm using `lighttpd`.

I'm trying to redirect a series of static URLs, and I want it to work whether or 
not the trailing slash is present:

```
http://localhost/mis
http://localhost/mis/
```

I've tried the following, and all sorts of variations, but I always get a match only with the trailing slash present:

```
url.rewrite-once = (  "^(.*)/$" => "$1/" )
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^([^?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "$1.php$2" )
```

If:

```
http://localhost/mis
```

not working and got 404 - not found

But if:

```
http://localhost/mis
```

It's working OK.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not end in a '\', make rewrite it to end in a '\':

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^(.*)[^/]$" => "$1/" )
```